# Echo In another page

Tags: php

I want to display the message in my code.php file

```
 if( $e->getCode() == 23000)
    {
        $message = 'Username already exists';
    }
```

on my index.php in `<p></p>`

If getcode=2000 I  want to redirect to index.php and echo the message

How do I make it work.

Thanks

Comment: If your page has a .html extension, then your only option is to make an ajax request to the PHP page.

Comment: To use `php` code your file has to be in `.php` extension.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju i have changed it to index.php

Comment: jack, You have two files? Please, give some more detaiuls of what You want to achieve.

Comment: @DarkAnavger yes 2 files

Answer (score -1):

To display or to print any php variable use `echo`

In code.php

```
 if( $e->getCode() == 23000)
 {
     $message = 'Username already exists';
     header("Location: index.php?message=".$message);
 }
```

in index.php

```
if(isset($_GET['message'])){
    $message = $_GET['message'];
} else {
    $message = "";
}
 <p><?php echo $message ?></p>
```

Comment: i have 2 files code.php and index.php. the message is code.php and the <p> in is index.php

Comment: yes  if( $e->getCode() == 23000) redirect to index.php and echo the message